# ui-router error: Cannot read property '$$animLeave' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got the error `"Cannot read property '$$animLeave' of undefined"` after upgraded my application from `angular 1.5.0 to 1.6.5` with `ui-router 1.0.5`(Original ui-router version 0.2.15).
Some routes works well, but some not, could your guys kindly give me some help?
Thanks a lot!

HTML:
[image]

Router:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: show the html code

Answer (score 1):

After i added `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` to `<a/>` element, it works! But someone can tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can cause using ng-app="App" and angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [ngModule.name]); together.

Try to delete ng-app directive

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the scoped `@uirouter` package? Check it out https://ui-router.github.io/blog/uirouter-scoped-packages/

Comment: Hi Mattias, i did use @uirouter/angularjs, and updated my package.json, not work at all.